# Formula for the Sampling Size of Population Mean (Variance Unknown)

Tags: probability, estimation

In my class we learned the formula for finding the sample size $n$ needed to estimate the population mean $\mu$ within a bound $b$ with a level of confidence of $100(1 - \alpha )$% to be 
$$n = \left(\frac{z_{\alpha / 2} * \sigma}{b}\right)^2$$

This formula works provided we are given the population variance or standard deviation. How would one figure this sort of problem out if $\sigma$ is unknown? Or is there another formula to use in this situation?

Comment: We cannot estimate how surely we land in a given interval if we don't know how dispersed the distribution is.  And variance is a measure of dispersion.

Comment: That makes sense. So I guess that answers my question then